# How to add media uploading to buddypress posts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

Trying to add a cover picture with title and body to a buddypress post. I can't find the relevant hook for buddypress to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated

I tried using buddypress hooks which allowed me to add title but I couldn't find anything related to media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BuddyBoss commercial theme has implemented a feature that attaches an upload button to the activity updates post form – SEE: http://buddyboss.com/

Theirs also afew plugins that adds photo uploading, such as BP Albums – SEE: https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bp-album/ but they are independent of the activity updates post form.